# vb.net Website Login

Tags: vb.net, post, authentication, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse a webpage using HTML Agility Pack in vb.net.  When I call the page that I want to parse I get redirected to a login page.  This is not a problem since I have an account with this website but I need to know how to log into this page from within my program.  My code so far is below:

```
Dim logincookie As CookieContainer
Public cookies As New CookieContainer

 Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'Web Scrape Balance Sheet - Quarterly
    Dim wreqBalQtr As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/incomeStatement/detail?stmtType=BAL&perType=INT&symbol=goog")
    wreqBalQtr.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5"
    wreqBalQtr.Method = "get"
    Dim proxBalQtr As IWebProxy = wreqBalQtr.Proxy
    proxBalQtr.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Dim documentBalQtr As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    Dim webBalQtr As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
    webBalQtr.UseCookies = True
    webBalQtr.PreRequest = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(AddressOf onPreReq)
    wreqBalQtr.CookieContainer = cookies
    Dim resBalQtr As HttpWebResponse = wreqBalQtr.GetResponse()
    documentBalQtr.Load(resBalQtr.GetResponseStream, True)

    Dim str As String
    str = documentBalQtr.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
    If str.Contains("Enter your Reuters.com account info") = True Then

        'NEED TO LOG INTO THE PAGE THAT IS CURRENTLY PULLED UP

        Dim TotalCurrentAssets = documentBalQtr.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='dataTable financials']/tr[13]/td[3]")
        Dim TotalCurrentLiabilities = documentBalQtr.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='dataTable financials']//tr[29]//td[1]")
        MsgBox(TotalCurrentAssets.InnerText)
    Else
        Dim TotalCurrentAssets = documentBalQtr.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='dataTable financials']/tr[13]/td[3]")
        Dim TotalCurrentLiabilities = documentBalQtr.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='dataTable financials']//tr[29]//td[1]")
        MsgBox(TotalCurrentAssets.InnerText)
    End If

End Sub

Private Function onPreReq(ByVal req As HttpWebRequest)

    req.CookieContainer = cookies
    Return True

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do with the base .NET library (the HTTP classes). I'd also look at WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) to see if it has an easier way.

If you are in luck, the site is using HTTP Basic Authentication which is pretty easy to program against. I would check the HTML and the HTTP headers to see what authentication method is called for.